# Output text file in html table using ruby views (ERB)

Tags: html, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have a text file which I want to output on a table in HTML using the lines as markers. The text file is formatted thus:

```
Admin logged out at 2018-02-13 13:21:30 +0000
Admin logged in at 2018-02-13 13:33:08 +0000
Admin logged out at 2018-02-13 13:46:07 +0000
```

And goes on for hundreds of lines.I am trying to run it using a view (ERB) file. Any Ideas on how to do this? The best I have been able to do is:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Log of activities</th>

  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @logfile.each do |line| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= logfile %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

where "logfile" is the filename. Of course it is wrong. I can't figure it out. I am running the file on Sinatra, and I use bootstrap to style the html.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `<td><%= logfile %></td>` be `<td><%= line %></td>` ?

I'm guessing that you can load the file already and just want to render it in the view.